# Source code of jar.exe - is it available

Tags: java, c, source-code

This may seem an odd question, but I want to create an executable which runs under Windows written in C++.  The program needs to be able to update a jar file even if Java is not installed on the target machine.  I have seen the src.zip in the Java JDK folder and the jar folder but this is Java code.  I assume jar.exe is written in C or C++?  Is it possible to see the jar.exe source code?  If so where would I find that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, `jar.exe` is just a thin wrapper around a Java implementation found in the package `sun.tools.jar`.

But a JAR file is simply a [ZIP archive with a metadata directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html). You can use any ZIP implemetation such as [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) to manipulate JAR files.